# List IP addresses of all validators

Tags: polkadot, kusama, network

Is it possible to determine all of the IP addresses of validators on the network? I imagine it is necessary to be able to, but is there a direct call that can be made to a running validator node?

Edit:
I've tried calling `authority-discovery` a few ways, but it seems there are issues accessing it due to private fields. I haven't found any examples of it being called directly except for tests, which have their own pseudo instantiations (not sure the proper Rust terminology). The supposed "polkadot-sdk" is starting to feel a little "black box".

```rust
let (worker, service) = sc_authority_discovery::new_worker_and_service(
    client.clone(),
    network.clone(),
    Box::pin(dht_event_stream),
    authority_discovery_role,
    prometheus_registry.clone(),
);
```

This is from a test, but I haven't seen a clean example of the `client` and `network` objects being created in the docs or any other project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`authority-discovery`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/client/authority-discovery) to get the current and next set of authorities but I'm not aware of any direct calls that you can make to fetch the IP addresses of validators.

The look-up yields a `Vec<Multiaddr>` which contains the addresses the authority can be reached at.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Rust and working code examples in the Substrate docs seem to be sparse, is it possible to show a simple example of getting data back from this function?